# Left joining two tables, if null default to 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, null, left-join

I am left joining a table and multiple subqueries in postgresql.

In one of the first joins, I am joining a table with a list of player ids and names to a subquery selecting their associated wins. Some players however, have not yet had a win.

Below is the query and the output:

```
select players.player_id, players.name, b.wins 
from players 
left join 
(select winner, count(winner) as wins from outcomes group by winner) b 
on players.player_id = b.winner;


 player_id |       name        | wins
-----------+-------------------+------
       500 | person 1          |    3
       501 | person 2          |
       502 | person 3          |    1
```

I would like to know how I can automatically have this query default to wins being 0 if the value in that column comes up as null. I would like the above table to look like this:

```
player_id |       name        | wins
-----------+-------------------+------
       500 | person 1          |    3
       501 | person 2          |    0
       502 | person 3          |    1
```

- I plan to make this a view, so I don't see a way to make the column's default value 0.
- I've had a look around on stackoverflow and google, but there seems to be a lot of responses for mysql but not postgresql
- Those responses using postgresql seem very complex to me.
- I hope this will also assist other having similar difficulties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use `coalesce()`:

```
select p.player_id, p.name, coalesce(w.wins , 0) as wins
from players p left join 
     (select winner, count(winner) as wins
      from outcomes
      group by winner
     ) w
     on p.player_id = w.winner;
```

This is ANSI standard SQL and will work in most databases, include MySQL and Postgres.